# AND clause with IN function to compare/validate values from subquery

Tags: oracle, plsql

Greeting,
In the hypothetical scenario, I have a procedure with with an update statement which works by updating the values of specified table with the variable inputs. However, I have five AND clauses with an IN comparison function to validate if the variable values exists with the tables specified in the subquery inside the parenthesis. The procedure executes as expected but no value are updated. The value from the variables exist in the tables specified in the subqueries. Without these five AND clauses, the procedure updates the values as expected but I need to make these validations. Please let me know what could be the issue or if these is a better way to perform this validation. Please also see the image for reference on the specific code. Thank you in advance.

```
DECLARE 
VAR1 DATE := TO_DATE('11/15/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
VAR2 VARCHAR2(25) := '0000809349';
VAR3 NUMBER := 2017;
VAR4 NUMBER := 4;
VAR5 DATE := TO_DATE('11/18/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY');

BEGIN

UPDATE MFT 
SET PD = VAR1,
    JI = VAR2,
    FY = VAR3,
    AP = VAR4,
    DPD = VAR5
WHERE RSN = 9097
AND VAR1 IN (SELECT PD FROM MEC)
AND VAR2 IN (SELECT JI FROM CGL)
AND VAR3 IN (SELECT FY FROM CGL)
AND VAR4 IN (SELECT AP FROM CGL)    
AND VAR5 IN (SELECT DPD FROM CGL)
AND PD = TO_DATE('06/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND JI = '0000911979'
AND FY = 2017
AND AP = 12
AND DPD = TO_DATE('06/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
COMMIT;
END;
```

[image]

Comment: It's as simple as at least one of the `and`ed conditions doesn't return true. BTW you really should be using aliases for your tables and then qualify all columns with the table they are supposed to be coming from, eg `PD` should exist in `MFT` but you're selecting it from `MEC`, if the column doesn't exist in `MEC` (because of a typo etc) then the query will probably not be doing what you expect.

Comment: Hi @AndrewSayer, Thank you for your feedback. I have provided the aliases and qualified them to their perspective tables and seems to work for exiting values. I will test and see if it works for non-existent values.